# Unable to bypass a mapping using Spring security and JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have been trying to implement basic spring security and JWT (Access and Refresh Tokens) to add a basic security to my application (Using Spring Boot, Lombok etc.)

The problem I am facing is that when I try and access the `/token/refresh` or `/abc` mapping, I receive a 403 Forbidden error (Used Postman).

I am providing the basic code for what I have done so far. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please let me know.

**ApplicationSecurity.java**

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/authenticate");
        
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/token/refresh").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/abc").permitAll();
            
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilter(authenticationFilter);

        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**PasswordEncoderConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoderConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
@Log4j2
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        
        log.info("Username : "+username);
        log.info("Password : "+password);
        
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
        String accessToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+TokenExpiryTime.ACCESS_TOKEN.getValue()))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("role", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0))
                .sign(algorithm);
        
        String refreshToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+TokenExpiryTime.REFRESH_TOKEN.getValue()))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);
        /*response.setHeader("access_token", accessToken);
        response.setHeader("refresh_token", refreshToken);*/
        
        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<String, String>();
        tokens.put("access_token", accessToken);
        tokens.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }
    
}
```

**CustomAuthorizationFilter.java**

```
@Log4j2
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/authenticate") || request.getServletPath().equals("/token/refresh")
                || request.getServletPath().equals("/abc")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else {
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            
            if(Utils.isNotNull(authorizationHeader) && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
                    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
                    String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                    String role = decodedJWT.getClaim("role").asString();
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                    
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error logging in : "+ e.getMessage());
                    response.setHeader("error", e.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
//                  response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
                    
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    error.put("error", e.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            }else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    private String password;
    
    private UserRole role;
    
    private UserStatus status;
    
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService{

    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        log.info("Saving new User : ",user.getName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String email) {
        log.info("Get User : ",email);
        return userRepo.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(long id) {
        return userRepo.getById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepo.findByEmail(email);
        
        if(!Utils.isNotNull(user)) {
            log.error("Email does not exist!");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email does not exist!");
        }else {
            log.info("User found!");
        }
        
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()));
        
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

Other Service and Repo have created with the usual flow.

The major issue is that I am unable to access `/token/refresh` or `/abc` but I am able to get the Users list with the `/users` mapping if I send the **Access Token** in the Authorization Header.
Any solution anyone can think of here?

Comment: Can you create a github repo to take a look ?

Comment: First of all spring has already built in jwt support, so you dont need your filters. Most likely this is CORS try adding `.cors().disable()` enable spring security debug logs, and it will tell you exactly your problem. But so you know, this is not how you implement jwts in spring security.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for pointing this out. I am really new at Spring Security. Can you please let me know the best way do this. Also, it will be helpful if you could share some resources for the same.
Thanks a lot for this info. Although I was able to resolve the issue by bypassing the requests in the Authorization filter. i will try your solution as well.

Comment: I would suggest you use google to find the official spring security documentation an read the chapter on jwts.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this in ApplicationSecurity class to bypass security for the endpoints

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/token/refresh");
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/abc");
}
```